# Loading the google map using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

I am trying to implement google maps in to my page. I couldn't able to acheive it. I am just getting an empty container.
I am doing something wrong here ?

```
 <div class="container">
 <div class="map">
 <div id="map-container" class="z-depth-1-half map-container" style="height: 500px;"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

These are the script files

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    var map;
    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
      });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You talk about php and ajax in your question but the code provided shows neither. Can you be more specific?

Comment: rest of the code contains only the styling part.

Comment: I couldn't even load the map either way

Comment: Change this line to: map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-container').

Comment: You are referencing a wrong map wrapper in your javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Simple**: Your script must be: `<script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YourApiKey&callback=initMap"></script>`

If necessary, post an screen on your console web.

To know [more](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=en).

Comment: hallo..,it loads for a minute but suddenly "oops,something went wrong" this page didnt load google maps..this is the error

Comment: @yuvii_10 maybe API keys??

Comment: You need get an `key`. Acess the [site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=en) and press "GET KEY"

Comment: @JordiCastilla exact!

Comment: I guessed so @Jorge but IMHO, this is already a new question `:P`

Comment: @JordiCastilla who knows a post later on this :)

Comment: @yuvii_10 nice! :)